# Outputting video in parallel on clock

Tags: python, c, linux, raspberry-pi, video-encoding

I'm trying to output video in parallel format to a display using a Raspberry Pi.

To accomplish this, I need to set 8 pins to YUV422 data, and then clock them in at 54 MHz via the GPIO.

I've read that it's unlikely this is possible using a high-level library like Python's GPIO library, so I'll need to go down to a C-level library to get the performance that I need.

As someone with a C++ background, setting the GPIO pins to a a YUV422 color is pretty straightforward; what I've found intimidating so far is how to set the clock.

I know this feels like a simple question, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the clock to such a high speed, or even finding out if it's possible with a library like WiringPi or if I'll need to go straight to the hardware clock.

Can anyone provide me with a pointer to either documentation or a code snippet that can help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good application for a Raspberry Pi. It is probably impossible to generate 432 Mbit/sec of output at a consistent clock rate from any userspace application, Python or otherwise.

You should probably consider using a different development board which explicitly supports parallel video output.

That being said, it *might* be possible using the [parallel display interface](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#parallel-display-interface-dpi), which will generate parallel video output (as a Linux video device!) directly on a set of the Pi's pins. It's really intended for RGB video output, but it can probably be repurposed for YUV output with an appropriately modified image.